# How to set var to null in sql query

Tags: php, sql

I am fetching value from drop down and using that value in query. When I don't select any value it isn't showing null or ' ', instead it is showing var=". How do i resolve that. I need to do this Because i am using `$('#select1').val() ? $('.select1td').show() : $('.select1td').hide();` in jquery that's why i need to do this. Here is my code:

```html
<select id="select1" name="select1" style="width: 190px; display: block;"><option selected value="" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option><?php 
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM searchdate ";
        
$result = @mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    echo "<option  class='name' value=' " . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
    }
?></select>
<?php
$count=1;
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","table");
$select1=isset($_POST['select1']) ? trim($_POST['select1']):'';

echo $sql="SELECT name FROM table WHERE name='".$select1."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

When  I don't select any value in drop down the query shows name="

Comment: please consider using `MySQLi` extension. The `MySQL` and the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and removed since php 7.0

Answer (score 0):

use `empty()` function instead of `isset()` function. It checks both variable is set and value is empty or not.

```
$select1=!empty($_POST['select1']) ? trim($_POST['select1']):'';
```

put this statement in if condition as:

```
    if($select1){
     $sql="SELECT name FROM table WHERE name='".$select1."' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    }else{
   echo "Please choose an option";
}
```

In javascript:

```
if($('#select1').val()){
$('.select1td').show()
}else{
$('.select1td').hide()
}
```

Comment: I need to do this because i am checking through jquery if select1.val is selected i.e. $('#select1').val() ? $('.select1td').show() : $('.select1td').hide();

Comment: there is better option to use `if and else` condition. JS if is very powerful you need to value in `if` then it will check as `if($('#select1').val()){$('.select1td').show()}else{$('.select1td').hide()}`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
<select id="select1" name="select1" style="width: 190px; display: block;"><option selected value="" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option><?php 
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM searchdate ";
        
$result = @mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    echo "<option  class='name' value=' " . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
    }
?></select>
<?php
$count=1;
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","table");
$select1 = trim($_POST['select1']);// you should trim first then check it with isset
$select1=isset($select1[0]) ? $select1:'NULL';

echo $sql="SELECT name FROM table WHERE name='".$select1."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: But that Null isn't doing something with my jquery

Comment: you said in the question's title: "How to set var to null in sql query" and I answered what you asked.